# jQuery inside PHP repeat region

Tags: php, jquery

I want to make a jQuery tooltips inside a row in repeat region

I made it but when the repeat region happens , the jQuery works just in the first row !

Anybody can help ?

```
<style type="text/css">

/* trigger button */
  #download_now {
    background:transparent url(/media/img/downloadnow.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    display:block;
    height:44px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-999em;
    width:159px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  /* mouseover state */
  #download_now:hover {
    background-position:0 -44px;
  }

  /* clicked state */
  #download_now:focus {
    background-position:0 -88px;
  }

  /* tooltip styling */
  .tooltip {
    display:none;
    background:url(/media/img/tooltip/black_arrow_big.png);
    height:163px;
    padding:40px 30px 10px 30px;
    width:310px;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#fff;
  }

  /* a .label element inside tooltip */
  .tooltip .label {
    color:yellow;
    width:35px;
  }

  .tooltip a {
    color:#ad4;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
</style>


<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #884509;
}
-->
</style>

<center>
<table width="836" border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#999900">
    <td width="16">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="16">ID</td>
    <td width="85">EMAIL</td>
    <td width="85">USERNAME</td>
    <td width="115">E-CONFIRMED</td>
    <td width="200">WAITING PASSWORD</td>
    <td width="163">PASSWORD</td>
    <td width="104">ACTIVATE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php do { ?>
      <td height="26" bgcolor="#99FF00">
                                        <? include("../infos.html"); ?>
                                        <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
                                        <script language="javascript">
                                         $("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'}).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'up', bounce: true } });
                                        </script>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#99FF00"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99FF00"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['email']; ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99FF00"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['nick']; ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99FF00"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['email_confirmation']; ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99FF00"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['waiting_pass']; ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99FF00"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['pass']; ?></td>
      <td bgcolor="#99FF00"><form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
        <table align="center">
          <tr valign="baseline">
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Pass:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pass" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['waiting_pass'], ENT_COMPAT, ''); ?>" size="32" /><br>
              <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['id'], ENT_COMPAT, ''); ?>" size="32" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr valign="baseline">
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Update record" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>" />
      </form>
      </td>
  </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>
</center>
```

This is the code above, please try it on a localhost to check the problem.
NOTE: i deleted the recordset , if you want me to include it , tell me .

Comment: Without some relevant code we can't really help you.

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Okay give me a second ..

Comment: Okay i edited the Post, the code is above ..

Comment: You're including jquery and initing the tooltip for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you posted some code to show what is causing the problem, but one guess would be that you might be trying to add multiple copies of a javascript object (the jQuery tooltip) but using the same identifer for each instance ... if so .. add the row number to the tooltip id to make the instance name unique to the row ..

What does your debug console tell you is wrong ? or Firebug ?? Perhaps you could post any error messages from those too.

Comment: there is no error message, but the tooltip works just in the first row.
I will try what you said and i'll back .. thanks

Comment: Just seen the code ... I don't know jQuery .. but I'll bet a buck that #download-now is the tooltip id ... you can't have multiple dom nodes with the same id. If you only want one tooltip (which your css seems to suggest) then you need to instantiate it outside the loop and then trigger it on each line ...

Comment: I changed it to : 
`<script language="javascript">
              $("#<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'}).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'up', bounce: true } });
          </script>`

Comment: after it was :
`<script language="javascript"> $("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'}).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'up', bounce: true } }); </script>`

Comment: But no positif results .... :/

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm going to go and look at jQuery a bit more .. sorry I couldn't help any more than that.

Comment: You gave me an idea that the prob has relation with id.
thats very helpful btw